# Why the abline does not through the origin? Multiple linear regression R

Tags: r

Hellow,

1. In the first time,I want to do a multiple linear regression based on 3 parameters (d=fn(a,b,c).

   ```
   ##
   data<-read.table(file=file.choose(), sep="\t", header=TRUE)
   head(data)

   # model

   model=lm(d~a+b+c,data=data)
   vals=round(predict(model),2) 
   vals
   summary(model)

   plot(data$d,vals,xlim=c(0,1.2),ylim=c(-0.2,1.2),,col='orange')
   model=lm(data$d~vals)
   coef(model)
   abline(model, col="orange",lwd=2)
   ##
   ```

   But I have a result with a negative intercept, so I will probably have negative values.

   ```
   d = -0.3349742 + 0.9409406*a + 0.0027562*b + 0.0222850*c
   ```
2. In order to avoid these negative values, I tried to force the model through the origin 0

   ```
   # model through origin 

   model0=lm(d~a+b+c-1,data=data)
   vals0=round(predict(model0),2) 
   vals0

   par(new=T)

   plot(data$d,vals0,col='blue')
   model0=lm(data$d~vals0)
   coef(model0)
   abline(model0, col="blue",lwd=2)
   ```

   This is true in the new model does not intercept,

   ```
   d = 1.0716260 * a + 0.0012543 * b +  0.0033465 * c
   ```

   But when I display a graph between observed and modeled parameter (d), the curve does not through the origin. it displays a curve with an intercept = -0.2205448

How can I force my regression through 0, and have a model fn = (a, b, c) without the intercept? and without much change in the shape of the first curve (ie it must remain close to the curve 1: 1)

Thank you

```
data 

a   b   c   d
0.351   300 8.30    1.20
0.396   293 7.52    1.09
0.300   278 7.37    1.09
0.513   263 7.81    1.08
0.469   286 2.49    1.05
0.411   290 6.26    1.04
0.39    191 10.89   0.98
0.49    221 6.57    0.91
0.40    226 7.29    0.88
0.35    286 6.91    0.86
0.40    217 4.98    0.85
0.32    249 5.80    0.83
0.341   262 4.45    0.82
0.24    238 6.91    0.79
0.34    185 7.22    0.78
0.35    249 9.12    0.76
0.42    232 6.73    0.75
0.45    185 10.06   0.73
0.24    217 8.46    0.73
0.29    189 5.93    0.73
0.39    202 3.83    0.71
0.16    242 5.79    0.71
0.20    235 7.94    0.70
0.17    237 7.91    0.70
0.39    144 6.67    0.69
0.21    226 5.93    0.68
0.38    151 6.82    0.68
0.30    206 5.59    0.67
0.45    190 5.02    0.67
0.26    191 6.29    0.66
0.35    253 4.26    0.66
0.43    232 5.23    0.66
0.38    195 3.56    0.65
0.31    156 9.86    0.64
0.22    181 5.07    0.63
0.30    142 3.79    0.62
0.18    181 7.02    0.61
0.40    157 11.01   0.58
0.308   164 4.44    0.57
0.20    181 3.84    0.57
0.14    197 3.98    0.56
0.39    129 10.87   0.55
0.38    167 5.96    0.55
0.12    190 4.81    0.53
0.28    188 6.47    0.52
0.31    128 3.15    0.51
0.23    146 5.28    0.49
0.31    195 6.34    0.49
0.315   156 3.30    0.49
0.21    152 4.67    0.48
0.42    157 3.24    0.47
0.25    148 4.69    0.47
0.14    191 5.61    0.47
0.18    113 5.96    0.46
0.280   149 7.78    0.46
0.278   157 2.50    0.46
0.13    130 5.50    0.46
0.17    152 4.96    0.46
0.23    138 5.37    0.44
0.14    169 5.21    0.44
0.180   167 4.63    0.44
0.18    123 4.91    0.40
0.280   132 3.07    0.40
0.14    168 6.78    0.39
0.12    154 4.09    0.38
0.25    152 3.48    0.37
0.19    128 2.89    0.36
0.167   151 8.01    0.36
0.12    120 4.55    0.36
0.24    137 3.34    0.35
0.25    135 7.68    0.33
0.258   136 3.22    0.31
0.25    133 2.56    0.31
0.228   126 5.18    0.30
0.18    202 5.38    0.30
0.24    148 2.90    0.29
0.16    210 4.47    0.29
0.20    123 4.17    0.29
0.28    137 4.80    0.27
0.28    139 6.43    0.27
0.30    139 4.95    0.27
0.20    190 5.16    0.25
0.13    103 2.31    0.24
0.08    122 3.78    0.23
0.14    197 3.61    0.22
0.11    101 1.95    0.22
0.15    104 5.53    0.22
0.18    112 3.88    0.22
0.15    134 5.69    0.22
0.11    97  4.61    0.22
0.074   105 5.79    0.21
0.13    181 4.43    0.20
0.10    103 3.17    0.20
0.023   65  0.82    0.20
0.12    115 4.68    0.20
0.13    190 4.00    0.18
0.24    113 4.18    0.18
0.13    84  3.94    0.18
0.09    166 3.00    0.17
0.15    116 2.70    0.16
0.21    109 3.55    0.15
0.107   105 1.93    0.15
0.04    99  3.36    0.13
0.30    98  3.18    0.12
0.13    160 4.19    0.11
0.11    79  3.23    0.10
0.08    78  2.04    0.10
0.10    138 2.95    0.09
0.17    141 3.99    0.09
0.16    150 2.76    0.09
0.13    162 3.98    0.09
0.03    92  2.54    0.09
0.14    110 2.55    0.06
0.12    118 4.48    0.06
0.13    116 2.27    0.06
0.07    109 2.23    0.05
0.05    94  0.95    0.05
0.06    89  2.97    0.03
0.06    81  2.20    0.03
0.07    179 1.93    0.03
0.07    124 2.16    0.03
0.08    84  8.78    0.03
0.06    103 1.71    0.02
0.07    89  6.09    0.01
0.02    99  1.23    0.01
0.05    75  3.61    0.01
0.05    74  3.12    0.00
```

Comment: 1) If you would have an intercept, but force through 0, you would expect an intercept in modeled vs observed values. 2) Usually it is a bad idea to force regression through the origin. 3) If your dependent values can't be negative, you probably shouldn't use OLS regression, but a generalized linear model.

Comment: Thank you  Roland for your comment, but I can not apply generalized linear model : model<-glm(d~a+b+c, family=binomial(link="logit"))  because it requires values between 0 and 1

Comment: Are those percentage values? Possibly you could use beta regression.

Comment: Why is it important that when a, b, and c equal 0  that the predicted be 0? I don't see any situation like that in your sample data. They are always greater than 0.  Also there are other models besides logit  you an use with the glm.

Comment: No it is not values in%. I do not want the intercept = 0, just I want a model that gives me positive modeled value. My thoughts to avoid negative values, we must force him to go with 0. possible there are other ways!

Comment: From a rough back of the envelope calculation your model does not seem to lead to negative predictions over the range of the predictors so just exactly what is the scientific issue here?

Comment: If the model passes through zero, there is no negative modeled by against if it does not pass through zero, it is possible to have negative values. my question what is the method to use to determine a model without passing through 0 and without have negative values.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see with the `summary(model0)` command, `model0` does not contain an intercept term, but what you are plotting with the following commands:

```
model0=lm(data$d~vals0)
abline(model0, col="blue",lwd=2)
```

is not the model without intercept, but a model predicting `d` from the predictions of the model without intercept (`vals0`). This model does include an intercept, which seems to cause some confusion here. If you instead create `model0` by:

```
model0=lm(data$d~vals0-1)
```

you will get a linear model without intercept (note that this line will just be the line `y=x`).

If you cannot accept a model predicting negative values it is most likely a better idea to use some kind of generalized linear model as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thank you DGKarlsson for your answer , Through the origin I think not a good idea, but when I can not apply generalized linear model : model<-glm(d~a+b+c, family=binomial(link="logit")) because it requires values between 0 and 1

Comment: @tazrart While a GLM was suggested, logistic regression is not the only choice for a GLM. A GLM with a log link (say a gamma glm, for example) would be guaranteed to be positive.